# reject fails due to read-only in chef 11

Tags: chef-infra

Im getting a read only error when using reject. From my understanding only reject! should fail?

```
(Node attributes are read-only when you do not specify which precedence level to set. To set an attribute use code like `node.default["key"] = "value"') on line #3:

    1: <% @params[:servers].each do |server| -%>
   2: server {
   3:   <% server.reject{|key,value| key == 'location'}.each_pair do |name, value| -%>
   4:   <%= name %> <%= value %>;
   5:   <% end -%>
```

chef 11.10.4

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is a reported bug [CHEF-4844](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4844?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) on this issue and there is no "answer".

Comment: Thank you, i had only found the original gist thread before. So i agree

Answer (score 1):

chef attributes aren't exactly hashes and they don't support the same operations as hashes do. You'd need to deep copy that hash if you want to call hash methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you actually don't need a deep copy. You can use

`<% server.to_hash.reject{|key, value| key == 'location'}... %>`